# Is it possible to rescale a tkinter PhotoImage (not from a file)?

Tags: python, tkinter

Assume I have a 96 x 96 PhotoImage generated algorithmically (not from a file), e.g.:

```
import tkinter

IMG_W = 96
IMG_H = 96

class App:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.i = tkinter.PhotoImage(width=IMG_W,height=IMG_H)
        for row in range(0, IMG_H):
            for col in range(0, IMG_W):
                pixel = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (0x80, row, col)
                self.i.put(pixel, (row, col))
        c = tkinter.Canvas(t, width=IMG_W, height=IMG_H);
        c.pack()
        c.create_image(0, 0, image = self.i, anchor=tkinter.NW)

t = tkinter.Tk()
a = App(t)    
t.mainloop()
```

(Note: the code above is only to show a filled PhotoImage.  My real use case is reading pixels from a data stream that produces 96 x 96 pixel bitmaps.)

But 96 x 96 is mighty small.  Is there a way to scale the PhotoImage so it fills a larger Canvas?

(Scaling examples I've seen all use Pillow and assume that you're reading from a file.  AFAICT, that doesn't apply here.)

Comment: as I remeber `pillow.Image.open()` can read from `file-like` object - so you can create `io.BytesIO()` to simulate file in memory. And this is often method to use `Pillow` for generated images or for imaged downloaded from internet (without saving on disk)

Comment: You can set the pixels of an instance of `Pillow.Image` as well.  Then you can freely resize the image after updating the pixels.

Comment: `pillow.Image` can also create image from `numpy.array` - `Image.fromarray()` - and this may be faster to generate image.

Comment: eventually you can try `self.i = self.i.zoom(scale_x, scale_y)`

Comment: eventually you can try `self.i = self.i.zoom(scale_x, scale_y)` (or `.zoom(scale_both)`) bu this expect integer values - so you can't get some sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `PhotoImage.zoom(scale_x, scale_y)` (or `.zoom(scale_both)` but it needs `scale` instead of `size` and it allows only `integer` values so you can't scale ie. `6.25` to convert from `96` to `600`

```
def generate_photoimage(self):
    """Original generator."""

    print('generate_photoimage')
    
    self.i = tkinter.PhotoImage(width=IMG_W, height=IMG_H)

    for row in range(0, IMG_H):
        for col in range(0, IMG_W):
            pixel = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (0x80, row, col)
            self.i.put(pixel, (row, col))
  
    self.i = self.i.zoom(6)  # works with tkinter.PhotoImage but not `ImageTk.PhotoImage`
          
    return self.i
```

---

As @acw1668 already mentioned you can use `Image.new()` to create empty image, generate it  with `.putpixel()` and later `.resize()`.
Finally you can use it in `tkinter` with `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` instead of `tkinter.PhotoImage`

I'm not sure but for big images `.putpixel()` can be slow.
(Or maybe it was about `putpixel` in `PyGame`)

```
def generate_pillow_image(self):
    """Generate using numpy array."""

    print('generate_pillow_image')
    
    self.img = Image.new('RGB', (IMG_W, IMG_H))
    
    for row in range(IMG_H):
        for col in range(IMG_W):
            self.img.putpixel((row, col), (0x80, row, col))
    
    self.img = self.img.resize((600, 600), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
```

You may also use `numpy.array` to create data, put values using `arr[y, x] = val` or using regions like `arr[y_start:y_end:step, x_start:x_end] = val` (or using other functions in `numpy`). Later you can convert to `PIL.Image` using `.fromarray()`, resize it, etc.

```
def generate_numpy_array(self):
    """Generate using numpy array."""
    print('generate_numpy_array')
    
    self.array = np.ndarray((IMG_H, IMG_W, 3), dtype='uint8')
    
    for row in range(IMG_H):
        for col in range(IMG_W):
            self.array[row, col] = (0x80, row, col)
    
    self.img = Image.fromarray(self.array)
    #img.save('output.png')        
    
    self.img = self.img.resize((600, 600), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

    self.i = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
    
    return self.i
```

---

BTW:

`PIL.Image` allows to write image in file `.png`. `.jpg`, etc. but `tkinter.PhotoImage` can't do this.

`PIL.Image` can read and write in `file-like` object so you can use `io.BytesIO()` to create file in memory and use image from internet, or send file to internet - all without writing on disk.

`PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))` for file with data (ie. for reading)

`PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(), 'w')` for empty file (ie. for writing)

---

Full working code which I used for tests:

```
import tkinter
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

IMG_W = 96
IMG_H = 96

class App:

    def __init__(self, t):

        #self.i = self.generate_photoimage()
        #self.i = self.generate_numpy_array()
        self.i = self.generate_pillow_image()
        
        #c = tkinter.Canvas(t, width=IMG_W, height=IMG_H);
        c = tkinter.Canvas(t, width=600, height=600);
        c.pack()

        c.create_image(0, 0, image=self.i, anchor=tkinter.NW)

    def generate_photoimage(self):
        """Original generator."""
        print('generate_photoimage')
        
        self.i = tkinter.PhotoImage(width=IMG_W, height=IMG_H)

        for row in range(0, IMG_H):
            for col in range(0, IMG_W):
                pixel = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (0x80, row, col)
                self.i.put(pixel, (row, col))
      
        self.i = self.i.zoom(6)  # works with tkinter.PhotoImage but not `ImageTk.PhotoImage`
              
        return self.i       

    def generate_numpy_array(self):
        """Generate using numpy array."""
        print('generate_numpy_array')
        
        self.array = np.ndarray((IMG_H, IMG_W, 3), dtype='uint8')
        
        for row in range(IMG_H):
            for col in range(IMG_W):
                self.array[row, col] = (0x80, row, col)
        
        self.img = Image.fromarray(self.array)
        #img.save('output.png')        
        
        self.img = self.img.resize((600, 600), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

        self.i = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        
        return self.i

    def generate_pillow_image(self):
        """Generate using numpy array."""
        print('generate_pillow_image')
        
        self.img = Image.new('RGB', (IMG_W, IMG_H))
        
        for row in range(IMG_H):
            for col in range(IMG_W):
                self.img.putpixel((row, col), (0x80, row, col))
        
        self.img = self.img.resize((600, 600), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        #img.save('output.png')        
        
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)

    
t = tkinter.Tk()
a = App(t)    
t.mainloop()
```

Comment: A whole smorgasbord of choices!  Since I don't need more than integer scaling, I'll go with the first approach -- one less package to load.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an instance of `Pillow.Image` instead of `tk.PhotoImage` to store the pixels from the data stream.  Then you can resize the image to whatever size you want.

```py
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# size of image from a data stream
IMG_W = 96
IMG_H = 96

# size of canvas
CAN_W = CAN_H = 500

class App:
    def __init__(self, t):
        image = Image.new("RGB", (IMG_W, IMG_H))
        for row in range(IMG_H):
            for col in range(IMG_W):
                image.putpixel((col, row), (0x80, row, col))
        c = tkinter.Canvas(t, width=CAN_W, height=CAN_H)
        c.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        image = image.resize((CAN_W, CAN_H)) # resize the image to fit the canvas
        self.i = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        c.create_image(0, 0, image=self.i, anchor=tkinter.NW)

t = tkinter.Tk()
a = App(t)
t.mainloop()
```